# Cannot read property 'value' of null, signup form

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at many questions about this same issue, but I still can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="first" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="last" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="user" /><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="password" id="right" placeholder="Password" id="password" /><br />
    <input type="password" id="right" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm" /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg" method="POST" onclick="signup()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function signup() {
var f = document.getElementById("first").value;
var l = document.getElementById("last").value;
var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
var e = document.getElementById("email").value;     
var p = document.getElementById("password").value;
var p1 = document.getElementById("confirm").value;
if (f == "" || l == "" || user == "" || e == "" || p == "" || p1 == "") {
  alert("One or more fields are empty!");
  } else {
    alert("test");
  }
}
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Do you know exactly which line is throwing that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input ... id="right" ... id="password" />
```

Double ids in Password & Confirm password inputs.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. I'm stupid. I didn't see that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have two id's set on your password inputs.

```
<input type="password" id="right" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
```

The browser is reading the first ones only (id="right"), and therefore no nodes exist with the id's "password" & "confirm" when you attempt to use `.getElementById()`

Answer (score 0):

you are using two ids for a single field password and trying to fetch it by id.
remove id="right" from password field